# Group date range into months

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, group-by

Just stumbled into an interesting SQL problem.

I have a table of date ranges, each entry has a start and end date. From this I need to get the number of days in each calendar month.

For example if there is one event that starts 20-02-2014 and ends 10-03-2014 I need a result that lists 02-2014 with 8 days and 03-2014 with 10. This also needs to be summed across all events, I'm after the total number of days in each month.

I can think of how to do this using PHP but would like to see an SQL only solution.

EDIT:
To give a better idea of the situation here is something similar to my table http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4232b/1 and I would be after a result something along the lines of

```
+---------------------+
| year | month | days |
+---------------------+
| 2014 |     2 |    8 |
| 2014 |     3 |   18 |
| 2014 |     5 |   32 |
| 2014 |     6 |    1 |
| 2014 |     9 |    9 |
| 2014 |    10 |   10 |
| 2014 |    11 |   30 |
| 2014 |    12 |    1 |
+------+-------+------+
```

Hopefully didn't get any of the math wrong there :P

Comment: I bet this interesting problem is called homework.

Comment: What is the max number of months an event will take place over?

Comment: @Mihai Nope, it's just a problem that came up while working on a project. I've implemented the PHP approach for now.

Comment: @Kickstart There is no maximum, it's either going to be a few weeks or roughly 10 months with few in between values if that helps.

Comment: @Mihai, so what if it is homework?

Comment: @DanBracuk Technically nothing,but I woudnt give an answer to a question Do stuff for me while I take a smoke,although its my problem.

Comment: I left school 7 years ago. This genuinely just came up as part of a project and got me a bit interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some miscalculations in your desired output. Prove follows later.

To easily solve it, create a table containing simply dates, which is a good idea to have anyway. I did it like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_date_range;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_date_range(IN startdate date, IN enddate date)
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS date_range;
CREATE TABLE date_range(a_date date primary key);

SET @date := startdate;

WHILE (@date <= enddate) DO
INSERT INTO date_range VALUES (@date);
SET @date := @date + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
END WHILE;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

and called it like this:

```
CALL sp_date_range('2014-02-15', '2014-12-10');
```

Just make the date range large enough.

Then query your table like this:

```
select
year(a_date), month(a_date), count(*)
from
events e
inner join date_range d on d.a_date between e.start_date and e.end_date
group by 1, 2;
```

and the result will be this:

```
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| year(a_date) | month(a_date) | count(*) |
+--------------+---------------+----------+
|         2014 |             2 |        9 |
|         2014 |             3 |       19 |
|         2014 |             5 |       34 |
|         2014 |             6 |        1 |
|         2014 |             9 |       10 |
|         2014 |            10 |       11 |
|         2014 |            11 |       30 |
|         2014 |            12 |        1 |
+--------------+---------------+----------+
```

Now for the prove, that you miscalculated the desired result:

```
mysql> select
    -> *
    -> from
    -> events e
    -> inner join date_range d on d.a_date between e.start_date and e.end_date
    -> where month(a_date) = 2
    -> ;
```

Result:

```
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| event_id | start_date          | end_date            | a_date     |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
|        1 | 2014-02-20 00:00:00 | 2014-03-10 00:00:00 | 2014-02-20 |
|        1 | 2014-02-20 00:00:00 | 2014-03-10 00:00:00 | 2014-02-21 |
|        1 | 2014-02-20 00:00:00 | 2014-03-10 00:00:00 | 2014-02-22 |
|        1 | 2014-02-20 00:00:00 | 2014-03-10 00:00:00 | 2014-02-23 |
|        1 | 2014-02-20 00:00:00 | 2014-03-10 00:00:00 | 2014-02-24 |
|        1 | 2014-02-20 00:00:00 | 2014-03-10 00:00:00 | 2014-02-25 |
|        1 | 2014-02-20 00:00:00 | 2014-03-10 00:00:00 | 2014-02-26 |
|        1 | 2014-02-20 00:00:00 | 2014-03-10 00:00:00 | 2014-02-27 |
|        1 | 2014-02-20 00:00:00 | 2014-03-10 00:00:00 | 2014-02-28 |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
```

9 rows/days, you just counted 8.

Comment: Little bit surprised to have been out by more than one day but it's very possible :(

Comment: The calendar table is a nice point, we have one of those for calculating working day differences anyway. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Well, quick play. This copes with up to 100 months difference, but isn't tested that much (especially for edge cases such as when the 2 dates are both in the same month / year), and I suspect I might have got the date difference parameters the wrong way round somewhere so some might land up negative.

Also I have taken the days difference to not include the start date (as you have in the example of 8 days between the 20th Feb and the end of the month)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2013-01-01', INTERVAL MonthsDiff MONTH), '%Y %m'),
    IF (MONTH('2014-01-01') = MONTH('2013-01-01') AND YEAR('2014-03-01') = YEAR('2013-01-01'), DATEDIFF('2014-01-01', '2013-01-01'), 
    CASE
        WHEN MonthsDiff = 0
            THEN DATEDIFF(LAST_DAY('2013-01-01'), '2013-01-01')
        WHEN MonthsDiff = ((YEAR('2014-03-01') - YEAR('2013-01-01')) * 12) + (MONTH('2014-03-01') - MONTH('2013-01-01'))
            THEN DAYOFMONTH('2014-03-01')
        ELSE DAYOFMONTH(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD('2013-01-01', INTERVAL MonthsDiff MONTH)))
    END ) AS DaysDifferencePerMonth
FROM
(
    SELECT units.aMonth + tens.aMonth * 10 as MonthsDiff
    FROM
    (SELECT 0 AS aMonth UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units,
    (SELECT 0 AS aMonth UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
    HAVING ((YEAR('2014-03-01') - YEAR('2013-01-01')) * 12) + (MONTH('2014-03-01') - MONTH('2013-01-01')) >= MonthsDiff
) Sub1
```

EDIT - the solution above gave me an idea.

Pure SQL version (max of 999 days) for a pair of dates:-

```
SELECT YEAR(DATE_ADD('2014-02-15', INTERVAL units.aMonth + tens.aMonth * 10  + hundreds.aMonth * 100 DAY )) AS aYear,
        MONTH(DATE_ADD('2014-02-15', INTERVAL units.aMonth + tens.aMonth * 10  + hundreds.aMonth * 100 DAY )) AS aMonth,
        COUNT(*)
FROM
(SELECT 0 AS aMonth UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units,
(SELECT 0 AS aMonth UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens,
(SELECT 0 AS aMonth UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) hundreds
WHERE DATE_ADD('2014-02-15', INTERVAL units.aMonth + tens.aMonth * 10  + hundreds.aMonth * 100 DAY ) <= '2014-12-10'
GROUP BY aYear, aMonth
```

Putting that against your table of events:-

```
SELECT events.start_date, events.end_date, YEAR(DATE_ADD(events.start_date, INTERVAL units.aMonth + tens.aMonth * 10  + hundreds.aMonth * 100 DAY )) AS aYear,
        MONTH(DATE_ADD(events.start_date, INTERVAL units.aMonth + tens.aMonth * 10  + hundreds.aMonth * 100 DAY )) AS aMonth,
        COUNT(*)
FROM events,
(SELECT 0 AS aMonth UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units,
(SELECT 0 AS aMonth UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens,
(SELECT 0 AS aMonth UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) hundreds
WHERE DATE_ADD(events.start_date, INTERVAL units.aMonth + tens.aMonth * 10  + hundreds.aMonth * 100 DAY ) <= events.end_date
GROUP BY events.start_date, events.end_date, aYear, aMonth
ORDER BY events.start_date, events.end_date, aYear, aMonth;
```

Note both of these include the last day. Change the <= to a < if you don't want to count that day.

Comment: Interesting! I'd expect something like that would carry a pretty big performance hit? Will certainly have a play though, thanks :)

Comment: @Kickstart A little too complicated, don't you think?

Comment: @fancyPants Not sure of a simpler way to do it without relying on other tables.

Comment: Mmm, had a bit more of a play.